# Activiti Diagramm Editor lacks some elements?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, activiti

Looks like [Activiti's diagramm editor](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#activitiDesigner) lacks some elements descirbed in their guide. I'm especially looking for the [`Cancel End Event`](http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCancelEndEvent). If i try to alter the generated XML to have the correct node editor destroys my modifications by further edits.

Am i using an old version of the editor or these elements are really not implemented in the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Yaogiang's BPMN editor](http://bpmn.sourceforge.net/) is more featureful in scope of Activiti elements. So i'm moving on to that. I'm still testing it though.

[image]